# Почему не срабатывает автосвязывание метода?

Tags: php, symfony

собсвенно вот services.yaml

```
App\Dictionary\Validator\Fabric\Commands\CommandEntities:
        calls:
            - [setFetcher, ['@App\Dictionary\View\AbstractDictionaryFetcher']]
```

вот так использую в классе

```
private ?AbstractDictionaryFetcher $fetcher = null;

    public function setFetcher(AbstractDictionaryFetcher $fetcher): void
    {
        $this->fetcher = $fetcher;
    }


    public function validate($content,array $options =[]): bool
    {
        try{
            new Uuid($content);
            if(!array_key_exists(self::TABLE_NAME, $options)){
                $this->message = "related entity is not installed in dictionary field";
                return false;
            }
            if(!$this->fetcher->isHaveRow($options[self::TABLE_NAME],$content)){
                $this->message = "related entity  not found";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e){
            $this->message = $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

вызываю его таким образом

```
new $returnCommand;
```

где `$returnCommand = App\Dictionary\Validator\Fabric\Commands\CommandEntities`
но при вызове метода

```
$returnCommand ->validate($content, $options)
```

получаю ошибку
Call to a member function isHaveRow() on null

Почему, что я делаю не так и как правильно?

Comment: Правильно не создавать самому `$returnCommand` через `new`. Это должен делать symfony сам, при внедрении зависимостей. Почитайте как в этом фреймворке осуществляется внедрение зависимостей и в целом про DI контейнеры